# Chrome: cookies missing in POST requests from <form target="[...]">

Tags: forms, google-chrome, post, cookies

The application I am building uses **`<form target="website2">` to send POST requests to another website** (I am using this technique because the website does not have an API, and I do not need to know the response of the POST request).

Everything is working fine in Firefox: the user first needs to be authenticated in the external website, then all following POST requests have the necessary cookies to keep the user authenticated and execute the action.

However, **Chrome has an unexpected behavior**: after the user is authenticated, some POST requests are sent with the cookies, but **some POST requests are sent without the authentication cookies** (which means the action fails). There is no success/fail logic that I can understand, except that after a short period of inactivity (1 minute) the POST requests are almost always sent without the cookies (fail).

I have tested with simple GET requests (`<a target="website2">`), and every works as expected: Chrome sends the cookies with the requests, even after some inactivity (10+ minutes).

**Any idea what is hapenning, and how to fix it?**

Thanks